# Contextual inline menu doesn't appear on some inserted images

Tags: menu, tinymce, wysiwyg

The contextual inline menu appears on inserted images with the same domain name. It doesn't appear on outside images.

For instance: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/k5faab/35 you will notice that I added imagetools_toolbar: "openlink link unlink", to the tinymce.init. Try to insert an image ( https://www.paintthemoon.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/250x250.gif ) you will notice that the contextual menu is missing.

I am using TinyMCE 4.7. The issue is present on all browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is expected behavior due to how CORS works in the browser.  You can create an image proxy to address this as documented here:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/imagetools/#imagetools_proxy

Another alternative is to build your own method to fetch the image:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/imagetools/#imagetools_fetch_image

...but note that you still have to abide by CORS restrictions so the image proxy may be the more robust solution.